# Database update will not work

Tags: c#-to-vb.net

I know that you guys will find this simple, but can anyone tell me why I am getting a syntax error despite following every instruction on numerous sites?

My code in full is:

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
    dbSource = "Data Source = F:\Brett\Programming Projects\Roster\Roster.mdb"

    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
    con.Open()
    ' This is grabbing all the records from the listing table in the Roster Database
    sql = "Select * FROM Listing"
    ' Or selected columns
    'sql = "SELECT Listing.FName, Listing.LName FROM Listing"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)

    ' Populate the dataset with the data adaptor. This can be any name
    da.Fill(ds, "Roster")
    con.Close()

    MaxRows = ds.Tables("Roster").Rows.Count
    inc = -1

End Sub

Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
    Dim iRow As Integer = Me.Label1.Text
    Dim junk As Integer

    ds.Tables("Roster").Rows(iRow).Item(5) = Me.TextBox3.Text
    ds.Tables("Roster").Rows(iRow).Item(6) = Me.TextBox4.Text
    ds.Tables("Roster").Rows(iRow).Item(8) = Me.TextBox5.Text

    da.Update(ds, "Roster")

    'da.Update(ds)

End Sub

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim newtbl As DataTable
    Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

    newtbl = ds.Tables("Roster")

    Dim drCurrent As DataRow
    drCurrent = newtbl.NewRow()

    drCurrent(1) = "sfd"
    drCurrent(2) = "werter"

    newtbl.Rows.Add(drCurrent)

    da.Update(ds, "Roster")

End Sub
```

No matter what I do, I get this error message. Any help will be greatly appreciated as this is two days now...

I would show you my error but as usual, some peanut won't let me without some crap.. It states OleDbException was unhandled, Syntax error in Insert Into statement.

Comment: Which line is the error thrown from? What's the structure of the Roster table? Which columns do indexes 1 & 2 correspond to in btn_Add_Click()?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try wrapping your database calls in a try-catch block and inspect the InnerXml that's returned with the exception?

That might give you more information about the error that you're getting.